# When should I use the FACTORY_TEST permission in Android?

Tags: android, sdk, permissions, android-manifest

While looking for a way to [give root permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/root-permission-with-android-sdk) to an Android app, I read the official documentation and went through the permission FACTORY_TEST in the [Manifest.Permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) page.

> **public static final String
> FACTORY_TEST**
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Run as a manufacturer test
> application, running as the root user.
> Only available when the device is
> running in manufacturer test mode.
> Constant Value:
> "android.permission.FACTORY_TEST"

So I had my answer for the root question, but I was left with the FACTORY_TEST permission… Do you know when this permission should be used? I can't find a lot of documentation on the subject.

It's only for self educational purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do you know when this permission should be used?

It should be used by a device manufacturer. AFAIK, it cannot be obtained by an ordinary SDK application.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... Do you have any link/source?

Comment: @Rob: You cannot enable factory test mode without modifying firmware, AFAICT: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java&q=FACTORY_TEST%20package:android.git.kernel.org&sa=N&cd=14&ct=rc