# Service on Android 9.0 Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, service, xamarin.android

I am making an **application** to send msg and use a **service**, the problem is that the **service** on **Android 9** stops because there is a rule that in **energy saving force to stop the service.**

What I thought is to ask the user to allow skip energy saving for the application.

I tried and couldn't, someone help me?

I'll send the code I have to try help :\

***Xamarin.Android***

**Img Notification Starts Service:**

[image: notification]

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.1" package="Sms.Sms" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name="com.xamarin.example.DemoService" android:directBootAware="true" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Codes\Manifest file\Img:**

[All Files :)](https://mega.nz/#F!2S5yiY5C!IBwg1yULFbFGfiaHmfeDAg)

**If it's a bad question say don't hate, I try**

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the power saving mode programmatically.

It's bad practice to control the user's device settings from your app.

Rather consider suspending background services when battery levels are low.

Or to notify the user of low battery power and advising the user to switch of unnecessary settings like Bluetooth or WiFi.

[the settings to turn off the power saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309163/service-on-android-9-0-xamarin-android)

Comment: Yes, what I
I thought it was asking the user to disable power saving for a given application

Comment: @GonçaloGarrido You can enable/disable Battery Saver programmatically on rooted devices,could  refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369841/10768653