# How to run Android shell command from Unity3D

Tags: c#, android

I need to run Android command like this below from C# Unity3D Android app.

How it can be done?

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "ACTION_HIDE_STATUSBAR" --ei "ui" 2 --ez "state" true
```

Comment: You can't unless the device has been rooted.

Comment: Then use Process.Start, like any other C# program.

Comment: Simply -- Process.Start("am broadcast -a \"ACTION_HIDE_STATUSBAR\" --ei \"ui\" 2 --ez \"state\" true");  -- Doesn't work, so I think that it must be other method or I'm doing something wrong.. The same command from shell works of course.

Comment: Youre doing it wrong, anything after am must be passed as parameters to Process.Start

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("am", "broadcast -a \"ACTION_HIDE_STATUSBAR\" --ei \"ui\" 2 --ez \"state\" true"); - this didn't work also. I think that will be easier if you can tell me how correct method should be - maybe in answer?

Comment: the previous line you pasted should be the right one, does it raise any exception or error message?

Comment: No nothing showed on the debug console

Comment: Use this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Wt55bcHg that will output the exit code, that will give on the console the exit code, what will give us more info on why it doesn't works

Comment: I run this on Android so I change Console.WriteLine to Debug.Log.. but it doesn't write nothing. It's strange :/

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure your function is being executed?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Fuction jusr after this was executed.

Comment: @Gusman I'm sorry it was executed just before my Debug gui console was loaded. Now I have exit code 255

Comment: BTW. @Joe Blow why Unity3D tag was not correct for this question in your opinion?

Comment: Ok, am is a Java program and standard exit codes are only 0,1, it should be a custom code but I can't find it in the Am source code. Try to redirect the standar output stream of the process and read it with an StreamReader, it will return what the program would show on the console, so there should be the error message. But my bet is your process does not have privileges to execute am, this can give you a hint on how to run your app as administrator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194725/run-android-program-as-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by modified UnityPlayerActivity class after exporting to Android project.

After more research it seems that this is the only solution or alternatively it can be done via java plugin in similar way.