# How to open /dev/diag with super user permissions?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am developing an application for One Plus 6. This applications is using a shared library(lib.so) to perform some task. For the task it needs to open dev/diag first and then send some commands through code. Below is the code to open dev/diag:

```
fd = open("/dev/diag", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE|O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd < 0) {
    perror("open diag dev");
    return -8002;
}
```

I am able to build a executable with `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` written in `Android.mk` and with `ndk-build` command. I am able to run open the dev/diag with placing the executable in /system folder of android.

The thing that failing is to do the same with an android application.
I have tried following:

- Rooted the One Plus 6
- Call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")` in `MainActivity::onCreate`.
- Give `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>` in manifest.
- Then call the required jni function.

Please suggest how can I enable su access on a function which is opening dev/diag for me?

I have also tried to do the same with running executable commands using ndk-build executable in /system e.g.

For READ:

```
    // Run the command
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c /system/lib get key");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    // Grab the results
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        log.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    String allLogs = log.toString();
```

For WRITE:

```
    Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes("/system/lib set key " + value);
    // Close the terminal
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");

    os.flush();
```

and it is working fine. Still I am wondering how to do the same with shared library. Any help?

Comment: `exec("su")` is not going to do it alone. It doesn't superuser the *current* process but can be used to execute *new* processes as superuser.

Comment: Oh! Please suggest the solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194725/run-android-program-as-root

Comment: I already found this but I want to it with shared library instead of running any command. I want to directly call a jni function with root access.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send commands to the the `/dev/diag` device and activate the QCDM messages on a Pixel 3a phone. I did this in the [open source Android app Network Survey+](https://github.com/christianrowlands/android-network-survey-rooted).

Specifically, take a look at [this line of code](https://github.com/christianrowlands/android-network-survey-rooted/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/craxiom/networksurveyplus/DiagRevealerRunnable.java#L86), which is something like this:

```
new String[]{"su", "-c", "exec <path_to_shared_library>"};
```

That line of code builds the shared command that is then executed by the `ProcessBuilder`.

The source code for the shared library can be found [here](https://github.com/christianrowlands/android-network-survey-rooted/blob/develop/app/jni/diag_revealer.c). Note that I did not write the diag_revealer code, instead that was taken from the [Mobile Insight app](https://github.com/mobile-insight/mobileinsight-mobile).

I think maybe the problem you ran into is executing from `/system`. Instead, make sure the shared library is in your app's private directory. The actual code I used pointed to the app's files directory:

```
return new String[]{"su", "-c", "exec " + diagRevealer + " " + context.getFilesDir() + "/" + context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.raw.rrc_filter_diag_edit) + " " + fifoPipeName};
```

Comment: how would you pass the argv through the exec? @Craxiom

Comment: @MRDRAG, I passed them in after the command. In my example the `diagRevealer` was the command, I added a space, and then the concatenation that follows was argv[1] and `fifoPipeName` was argv[2].