# Facing problem with Rooted issue in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Root permission with Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/root-permission-with-android-sdk)

Android application is not getting root access though device is rooted. Is there any possible way for android apk to get root permissions ???

Answer (score 1):

refer: [How can I get root permissions through the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/root-permission-with-android-sdk)

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bla");
```

That causes SuperUser to show, which lets you either Allow or Block it from root access. This approach might not work if the user is not rooted.