# Grant administrator access to Android app

Tags: android, root, su

I want to know if this is possible and if it is how can I manage to do this.
When the app is installed it should root the device and grant su access to that app. After that it should unroot the device, keeping the su rights to that app.

Comment: Short answer: not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get root permissions through the Android SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk)

Comment: what do you want to try after rooting phone ? There can be some others way to do that.

Comment: I want to give root access to an app. Can this be done with a secure certificate?

Answer (score 1):

It will **not grant you SU access**, but it can give you access to your app

It is using the Device Administration APIs, you can read about it here:

[http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

it may help you