# How to copy a database

Tags: android, database

How can I copy **suggestions.db** in

```
/data/data/com.android.vending/databases/
```

**to**

```
/data/data/MY_PACKAGE/databases/
```

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with android dev. But I manage several sql databases.   So... What db are you dealing with? and, do you have access to a shell to run sql scripts?

Comment: can you clarify your question?you have to copy db pro grammatically or using window.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Harshid copy db programatically. access by my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that on a non-rooted phone due to security restrictions. If you want to use root, then refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5293771/361230).