# How to read files placed in root-folder?

Tags: android

I want to know how to read files placed in root folder. For instance let's take file `/init.trace.rc`. When I'm trying to read it I get exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /init.trace.rc: EACCES (Permission denied)

I thought that I need to get superuser access. I did it but that made no difference ((( I still can't read it. Could anybody help me? ...and also I wonder how file explorers like "RootExplorer" read that stuff?

Comment: You need to add root permissions to your app

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get root permissions through the Android SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently this is all you need to run to get root access:

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

taken from:

- [How can I get root permissions through the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk)

Comment: That or use RootTools library from Stericson. Keep in mind the device will NEED to be rooted.

Comment: My device is rooted and as I said above I requested root permissions and got them. But when I tried again to read that file I got the same exception!!! ((