# Using the root users to stop service in android

Tags: android, root

I'm an Android app developer. I want to kill the service running in the background, consuming resources. I tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime (). Exec ("sh" + packagename_to_stop)
```

But it did not work; Can someone help 
me? 
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to gain root access first,

[How can I get root permissions through the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk)

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

your app will have root access,
then you can execute your commands as Root user.