# Android Edit Sysctl Settings

Tags: android, linux-kernel, sysctl

In my app i need to edit sysctl settings in Android. I've seen few apps that can do this, for [example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.jandroid.sysctleditor) but i have no idea how do they do this programmatically, any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think i found the answer: sysctl.conf is located in the /system/etc folder. Ask for the root and edit it like any other text file.

- Ask for the root -
  [How can I get root permissions through the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk)
- Edit text file -
  http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523