# I am making a application which will help user to record its screen

Tags: android, root-access

I know this is possible in android API version 21, but I want to do it in the API version 19 or earlier. To achieve this task, I have to get root permissions. I don't know how to get root permission. How can this be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is something like:

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

That causes SuperUser to show, which lets you either  Allow or Block it from root access. This approach might not work if the user is not rooted. [Here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/) is a way you can test it.

[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk)